# Bash - pass arguments same way they were received

Tags: bash

I have a bash alias for my `hg` (mercurial) command that looks like this:

```
hg() {
  if [[ $1 == 'up' ]]; then
    if [[ $# == 2 ]]; then
      _update_bookmark $2
    else
      up
    fi
  else
    /bin/hg $@
  fi
}
```

My issue is with the final `else` case.  I want the arguments, as I received them in `hg()`, to be passed exactly the same way to `/bin/hg`.  My issue arises when I do something like `hg commit -m "my message here"` and it gets passed as something like `/bin/hg commit -m my message here`.  I tried both `$@` and `$*` - not sure which is more appropriate here but neither seemed to do the trick.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Also make sure you quote `"$2"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write `"$@"` (with double-quotes) to prevent word splitting while still keeping already-separate arguments separate.